# How many combinations to put books in $n$ packages - Whats wrong with my solution

Tags: combinatorics

There are $2n$ science fiction books, $3n$ thrillers and $5n$ drama.

We want to fix $n$ packages of books so that in each package there will be 2 sci-fi, 3 thrillers and 5 drama.

How many combinations are to do that?

I thought about organising let's say the sci-fi books in a row $(2n)!$ and take every 2 as one, so putting in order in $n$ packages is $n!$.
Same with the other genres so that the solution is $$(2n)!n!(3n)!n!(5n)!n!$$
But not sure if it's the right solution.

What do you think?
How can I know if this is a correct approach?

---

Correct me if I'm wrong, I think my mistake is that I don't need the $(n!)^3)$ I wrote cuz it counts inside the $(2n)!(3n)!(5n)!$,
But I do need to divide with the inner order of each group of 2's, 3's and 5's means divide by $(2!)^n(3!)^(5!)^n$

Comment: In your edit you are correct if the packages are ordered, but I suspect they are not. Then division with $n!$ repairs that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us first label the packings by $1,2,\dots n$.

We start with selecting $2$ sci-fi's, $3$ thrillers and $5$ drama's meant for the first package.

For that there are $\binom{2n}2\binom{3n}3\binom{5n}5$ possibilities.

Then for the second package there are $\binom{2n-2}2\binom{3n-3}3\binom{5n-5}5$ possibilities et cetera, so - if the order of the packages counts - then there are: $$\binom{2n}2\binom{3n}3\binom{5n}5\times\binom{2n-2}2\binom{3n-3}3\binom{5n-5}5\times\cdots\times\binom{2}2\binom{3}3\binom{5}5=$$$$\frac{(2n)!(3n)!(5n)!}{(2!)^n(3!)^n(5!)^n}=\frac{(2n)!(3n)!(5n)!}{1440^n}$$possibilities.

If the order of the packages does not count (and I suspect that is the case here) then every possibility has been counted $n!$ times above, and repairing this we find:$$\frac{(2n)!(3n)!(5n)!}{n!1440^n}$$possibilities.

Comment: Thank you, can you please explain what's wrong with my solution

Comment: Also, Should'nt it be $(2!)^n(3!)^n(5!)^n$

Comment: Yes, that is what it should be (I repaired).